# Extract Text with Formula between Values

Tags: visual-workflow, formula

I like extract a value from a field in Salesforce which is between two values.

**Value of the field:**

```
https://somewebsite.com/b2b/?twclid=someidfromtwitter&&utm_source=Twitter&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=supercampaign
```

**I tried the following:**

```
RIGHT(Landing_Page,FIND("utm_source=",Landing_Page)-9)
```

**The Result is:**

```
Twitter&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=supercampaign
```

I just want `Twitter`. I know, that I can "cut" some values by writing down a substraction. But the thing is, `utm_source` can also be `utm_source=someothercoolsocialmedia`.

How can I extract the value between `utm_source=*somvalue*`?

Comment: I think you want MID vs RIGHT.

Comment: This is the currenty state: 
MID(Landing_Page, FIND("utm_source=",Landing_Page)+11, (FIND("?utm_medium=",{Landing_Page)-FIND("utm_source=",Landing_Page)+11))

Mid works like (field, starting position, number of letters) - so currently i'm not able to calculate the number of letters-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the formular was not working correctly is the questionmark infront of utm_medium.

This is the working Formula:

```
MID(Landing_Page_URL, FIND("utm_source=",Landing_Page_URL)+11, FIND("utm_medium=",Landing_Page_URL)-1-(FIND("utm_source=",Landing_Page_URL)+11))
```

@cropredy: you are right.

Comment: As a service to the community, you should put in the answer the correct formula; use [edit].